# The meaning of "the Huffington Post of the right"

Tags: meaning-in-context

According to Wikipeida, "[Breitbart News Network ... is an American far-right syndicated news, opinion and commentary website founded in mid-2007 by American conservative commentator Andrew Breitbart, who conceived it as 'the Huffington Post of the right'.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breitbart_News)" I don't understand what "the Huffington Post of the right means exactly. I wonder if there is also "the Huffington Post of the left". Please help and thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The Huffington Post of the left is, well, The Huffington Post. It's a portal that's commonly perceived as liberal/left-wing leaning, providing aggregated news and blog articles with a certain degree of bias towards the liberal world view.

A "Huffington Post of the right" in that context would be a portal which operates on a similar principle, but catering to the right-wing world view rather than a left-wing one. So it would provide similar types of content and exhibit similar amount of bias, but lean towards the conservative world view rather than the liberal one.

Comment: "articles with a certain degree of bias towards the liberal world view." - alternatively, articles without a certain degree of bias towards the right-wing world view.

Comment: "Liberal" has a left orientation mainly in the United States. Elsewhere, a "liberal" POV on matters like taxation and free trade align with traditionally (pre-Trump) center-right positions, as with the Liberal Party in Australia and the Liberal Democratic Party in Japan. In any case, the center-left in the U.S. has preferred the term "progressive" for the last couple of decades, in part because of negative associations of "liberal" imparted in the last quarter of the 20th century.

Comment: In Britain, being a "liberal" is largely a matter of economic beliefs. I once heard Margaret Thatcher described as an "old-fashioned liberal of the Manchester School".

Comment: There is no Huffington Post "of the left". There is just The Huffington Post. People are on far right in the States mislabel all sorts of things. Here, whoever wrote that Wikipedia crap  must be quoting Breitbart, the bad news writer. Ha ha. Breitbart is really bad news. [ha ha]

Comment: @Lambie - "People on the far right in the States mislabel all sorts of things." - yes. So true. Like calling decent people "social justice warriors", and expressing non-far-right opinions "virtue signalling".

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Gawd, I never heard virtue signalling. These people are the new barbarians. And they are definitely "other". Ha ha.

Comment: _Virtue-signalling – the putdown that has passed its sell-by date_ [The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2016/jan/20/virtue-signalling-putdown-passed-sell-by-date) -"In many cases, the thinking goes like this (with the left a frequent target): 1. Bill is saying something right-on. 2. Virtue-signalling is when you say something right-on just to sound good 3. Therefore Bill is virtue-signalling. But 3. is not justified by 1. and 2."

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed explanations!